# Deadlock during simple update: ShareLock and AccessExclusiveLock

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have noticed occasional deadlocks in error logs, the reason is parallel update of the same row:

```
[1111]:LOG:  process 1111 detected deadlock while waiting for ShareLock on transaction 123456789 after 1000.095 ms
[1111]:DETAIL:  Process holding the lock: 2222. Wait queue: .
[1111]:CONTEXT:  while locking tuple (9999999,99) in relation "ccc"
[1111]:STATEMENT:  update ccc set modification_date_time=$1, ... where id=$7
[1111]:ERROR:  deadlock detected
[1111]:DETAIL:  Process 1111 waits for ShareLock on transaction 123456789; blocked by process 2222.
    Process 2222 waits for AccessExclusiveLock on tuple (9999999,99) of relation 55555 of database 66666; blocked by process 1111.
    Process 1111: update ccc set modification_date_time=$1, ... where id=$7
    Process 2222: update ccc set modification_date_time=$1, ... where id=$7
[1111]:HINT:  See server log for query details.
```

What happens in application is the following:

1. Hibernate loads the entity (row)
2. A field is being modified
3. Hibernate saves the entity to the database, resulting in the `UPDATE` statement

It's not clear why it happens, because it's just a normal update, and processes should not depend on each other. I understand it's a race condition, but from application point of view it's not important.

I don't fully understand, what is `ShareLock` and `AccessExclusiveLock`, so I have 2 ideas so far:

- When entity is modified, Hibernate/DB has to raise lock level, and it fails, because other thread already has some lock on this row. Solution - lock early?
- Sometimes transactions are simply too slow (> 1s), and deadlock gives a false positive. Solution - increase timeout?

Answer (score 2):

There must be more than one locked object involved for a deadlock to occur.

Check what other rows have been updated by the transactions. Perhaps you can turn on SQL logging if you can afford it.

Deadlocks can often be avoided by locking rows in some specific order, e.g. by ascending ID.

A deadlock cannot be caused by slow processing, although long transactions increase the danger.

If the deadlocks occur only rarely, don't worry about them. Just retry the transaction.